# Can't run React Native App due to react navigation errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I started making my first react native app but I keep running into issues with react-navigation. In my app.js file, I included

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

but I ran into this error: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGppl.jpg)

Before I used these import statements here:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

But ran into this error: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beeRF.png)

Which one should I use and how do I fix each error?

This is my App.js file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import profile from './components/Profile';
import messages from './components/Messages';
import home from './components/Home';
import signInScreen from './components/signInScreen';
import signUpScreen from './components/signUpScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() 
{
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName= "Sign In" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={signInScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up" component={signUpScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Messages" component={messages}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={profile}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which react-native-navigation  version do you using?

Comment: And what are you import from `react-native-gesture-handler` ? It's looked weird.

Comment: This looks like a react navigation 5 setup. Your first imports should be correct, `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/stack`.

Comment: I am using React-Native-Navigation version 5

Answer (score 0):

First of all install react-native-screens using this command

```
npm install react-native-screens
```

now change your code like this

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";
import profile from './components/Profile';
import messages from './components/Messages';
import home from './components/Home';
import signInScreen from './components/signInScreen';
import signUpScreen from './components/signUpScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

enableScreens(); //New line added

export default function App() {
  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
   /* spaces removed between the names */
   <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName= "SignIn" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
     <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={signInScreen}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={signUpScreen}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={home}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Messages" component={messages}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={profile}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);}
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your problem

Comment: I still got the same error. 

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context'))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by playing around with the react-navigation dependencies. I got some warnings saying that some of my dependencies were too new so I uninstalled and installed them again but I decided to try and install react-navigation again for the 3rd time from the react-navigation docs:[Install command for Expo managed Project](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project)

After that, my project started working.